# WP7 BackgroundAudioPlayer error code

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-audio

When using `BackgroundAudioPlayer` in Windows Phone 7 application. It sometimes cause errors, and `OnError` will handle it. The problem is that it show only the error code, and we can't know about it. When reading [Paul Annets's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/11/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-3.aspx). I found meaning of some error codes.

```
Exception.Message   Hex equivalent  Meaning
“-2147012889”       80072EE7        Can’t find the server (e.g. phone is in flight mode)
“-2147012696”       80072FA8        No available network connection
"-1072889830”       C00D001A        Can’t find media file (e.g. the MP3 file you were pointing to is no longer on the server)
“-2147467259”       80004005        Non-specific error code
```

Currently I encounter error code "-2147012865" (error.Data is of type `ListDictionaryInternal`) and I want to know its meaning?

P/S: If you have meaning of other error code, it would be great to share here